# Digital Ocean Bundle Install Killed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my website on digital ocean following this guide (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean) But when I do bundle install I get this message

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.....Killed
```

It stops me from continuing the next step. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You might not have enough memory to run the `bundle install` command. For clues, check the end of `/var/log/syslog` (you'll need to root access) to see if there are any warnings about memory being exhausted.

If that's the problem, you may need to upgrade to a bigger droplet with more resources.

Comment: But mine was just a simple website :(

Comment: The fact that adding swap solved the problem means you didn't have enough memory. I still recommend using a bigger droplet, since relying on swap is slow and generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this as well.  You need to build off a swap disk to be able to deploy.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem. But I am using Putty.exe to configure my digital ocean stuff, can I know which directory I'm messing with because it doesn't state. And can i know where is the swap disk located? i created it by following the tutorial link you shared

Comment: ```pwd``` will show you your current working folder normally but I don't know for sure in putty how it will handle it, as I am normally in the shell directly.